# Drawing a community in networkx, anything I am doing incorrectly?

Tags: matplotlib, graph, networkx, graph-theory

[image]
Trying to do something like this but I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx.algorithms.community as nxcom

G = nx.karate_club_graph()
greedy = nxcom.greedy_modularity_communities(G) 
#returns a list with type frozen sets within the list
#[{set1},{set2},{set3}]

pos = nx.spring_layout(G)  # compute graph layout
plt.axis('off')
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, cmap=plt.cm.RdYlBu, node_color=list(greedy.values()))
plt.show(G)
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code?  Are you getting any errors or are things just not being plotted in the right place?  What are you expecting to see versus what you're actually seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your issue comes from the way you are mapping colors to your communities. Since the `node_color` argument from `nx.draw_networkx_nodes` is expected to be a list of color (see doc [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html)), you will need to associate each one of your nodes with the color of its community. You can do that by using:

```py
c=plt.cm.RdYlBu(np.linspace(0,1,len(greedy))) #create a list of colors, one for each community
colors={list(g)[j]:c[i] for i,g in enumerate(greedy) for j in range(len(list(g)))} #associate each node with the color of its community
colors_sort=dict(sorted(colors.items())) #sort the dictionary by keys such
```

You can then convert the values of your sorted dictionnary into a list and pass it to the `nx.draw_networkx_nodes` with `nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos,node_color=list(colors_sort.values()))`.

See full code below:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx.algorithms.community as nxcom
import numpy as np

G = nx.karate_club_graph()
greedy = nxcom.greedy_modularity_communities(G) 
c=plt.cm.RdYlBu(np.linspace(0,1,len(greedy)))
colors={list(g)[j]:c[i] for i,g in enumerate(greedy) for j in range(len(list(g)))}
colors_sort=dict(sorted(colors.items()))
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos,node_color=list(colors_sort.values()))
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G, pos,labels={n:str(n) for n in G.nodes()})
plt.axis('off')
plt.show(G)
```

[image]